# applescript Calculator not working

Tags: applescript, calculator

I have made a calculator which should work but doesn't. The only part that works is the addition. this is my code:

```
   my Calculator()
on Calculator()
    display dialog "Calculator" buttons {"Add", "Multiply", "Divide"}
    if button returned of the result is "Add" then
        display dialog "What plus What?" default answer ""
        set a to (text returned of result)
        if a is equal to "q" then
            return
        end if
        display dialog "Next number" default answer ""
        set b to (text returned of result)
        set c to a + b
        display dialog "The answer is " & c buttons {"Start Again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            return
        else
            my Calculator()
        end if
    end if
    if button returned of the result is "Multiply" then
        display dialog "What times what?" default answer ""
        set a to (text returned of result)
        if a is equal to "q" then
            return
        end if
        display dialog "Next number" default answer ""
        set b to (text returned of result)
        set c to a * b
        display dialog "The answer is " & c buttons {"Start Again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            return
        else
            my Calculator()
        end if
    end if
    if button returned of the result is "Divide" then
        display dialog "What divided by what?" default answer ""
        set a to (text returned of result)
        if a is equal to "q" then
            return
        end if
        display dialog "Next number" default answer ""
        set b to (text returned of result)
        set c to a / b
        display dialog "The answer is " & c buttons {"Start Again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            return
        else
            my Calculator()
        end if
    end if
end Calculator
end
   end
```

it is an applescript code. I'm sorry if it is a nooby question but I need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using three `if/end if` statements to process the button returned, you should only use a single `if/end`, and utilize `else if` in between.  I have edited your code to fix it, and commented out the incorrect regions.

e.g.:

```
   my Calculator()
on Calculator()
    display dialog "Calculator" buttons {"Add", "Multiply", "Divide"}
    if button returned of the result is "Add" then
        display dialog "What plus What?" default answer ""
        set a to (text returned of result)
        if a is equal to "q" then
            return
        end if
        display dialog "Next number" default answer ""
        set b to (text returned of result)
        set c to a + b
        display dialog "The answer is " & c buttons {"Start Again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            return
        else
            my Calculator()
        end if
    else if button returned of the result is "Multiply" then
        display dialog "What times what?" default answer ""
        set a to (text returned of result)
        if a is equal to "q" then
            return
        end if
        display dialog "Next number" default answer ""
        set b to (text returned of result)
        set c to a * b
        display dialog "The answer is " & c buttons {"Start Again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            return
        else
            my Calculator()
        end if
    else if button returned of the result is "Divide" then
        display dialog "What divided by what?" default answer ""
        set a to (text returned of result)
        if a is equal to "q" then
            return
        end if
        display dialog "Next number" default answer ""
        set b to (text returned of result)
        set c to a / b
        display dialog "The answer is " & c buttons {"Start Again", "Quit"}
        if button returned of the result is "Quit" then
            return
        else
            my Calculator()
        end if
    end if
end Calculator
end
   end
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Sorry I rejected the edit, I didn't notice the changes